# Embedding Google moderator in my website

Tags: web, embedding, google-moderator

I am developing a website where i need to embed Google moderator in my website, i went through the help of Google but couldn't do it. So what are the steps to embed the Google Moderator to my website. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second result for 'embed google moderator':

First, place the following code in the HEAD section of your page:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/moderator/static/moderator-embed-api.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Next, create an empty element on your page with a specified ID that will contain the embedded Moderator page, for example

```
<div id=”moderator-embed-target”></div>
```

In your browser, open the existing Moderator page that you want to embed and retrieve the URL, for example:

```
https://www.google.com/moderator/#16/e=409f
```

For basic uses, below the target element you created above, include the URL of your Moderator page and the ID of the target element in this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
MODERATOR_embed("https://www.google.com/moderator/#16/e=409f", "moderator-embed-target");
</script>
```

For advanced uses, you can specify the height, width and language of the embedded page using code like below, instead of using the MODERATOR_embed function:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var mod = new MODERATOR("https://www.google.com/moderator/#16/e=409f"); 
mod.hl = "es"; 
mod.width = 1000; 
mod.height = 500; 
mod.embed("moderator-embed-target"); 
</script>
```

Putting it all together: Here’s a sample page that embeds this Moderator series using default properties:

```
<html>
<head> 
  <title>Embedding Moderator Sample</title>
  <script src="https://www.google.com/moderator/static/moderator-embed-api.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
  <div id="moderator-embed-target"></div> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
    MODERATOR_embed("https://www.google.com/moderator/#16/e=409f", "moderator-embed-target"); 
  </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

You can view this example in your browser here: http://google-moderator-api-samples.googlecode.com/hg/samples/simple-embed-api/simple-embed-api-example.html

**Information found at:**
https://sites.google.com/site/moderatorhelpcenter/home/embedding-moderator